# Target in Xcode has an E next to it

Tags: xcode

What does the E mean next to the 3 targets in Xcode? We have a bundle id and profile associated to each and are wondering how to consolidate these into the main target.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: Extension. Those look like notification extensions. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotificationsui/customizing_the_appearance_of_notifications